# Qual a diferença em usar sprintf em relação a usar variáveis dentro da string?

Tags: php

Vendo algumas bibliotecas e exemplos é comum encontrar o `sprintf` em algumas situações em que acho estranho.

[Lendo sua documentação notei que existem diversos tipos de formatação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php), entretanto vejo alguns casos que não vejo utilidade de utilizar isso, uma vez que apenas insere uma variável em uma string.

Um exemplo real, extraído do StatusPage.io:

```
$ch = curl_init(sprintf("%s/pages/%s/metrics/%s/data.json", $BASE_URI, $PAGE_ID, $METRIC_ID));
```

Um exemplo adicional, extraído da [Yubico/Yubikey](https://github.com/Yubico/php-yubico/blob/d996932598c6b3db83a356622be17c672416ff92/example/authenticate.php#L66):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT username FROM demoserver WHERE id='%s'",
           pg_escape_string($identity));
```

Qual é diferença do `strintf` contra isso:

```
$ch = curl_init("$BASE_URI/pages/$PAGE_ID/metrics/$METRIC_ID/data.json");

$query = 'SELECT username FROM demoserver WHERE id="'.pg_escape_string($identity).'"';
```

**Qual seria a vantagem de se utilizar o `sprintf` em situações como essa?**

Comment: Não vejo vantagem em situações como essa, Acho legal usar quando o argumento do `sprintf` é um argumento de uma função. Tem que balancear pra ver o que é necessário, e o que é firula alheia

Comment: Ei, acha que já pode marcar uma das respostas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `sprintf()` formata uma string baseado na ordem dos parâmetros definida no primeiro argumento, o que torna tudo muito dinâmico, permitindo formatar strings com muita flexibilidade.

Um exemplo de grande utilidade é quando precisa escrever dados em idiomas diferentes.

## Formatação para templates, saída de dados, etc.

Casos comuns são nomes de pessoas, pronomes de tratamento pessoal, endereços, etc.

O exemplo abaixo elucidada melhor:

```
// Define idioma. Modifique para "pt" e veja como é a saída dos dados.
$l = 'ja';

// tratamento pessoal
$t['ja'] = '様';
// nome da pessoa
$n['ja'] = array('name' => '太郎', 'surname' => '山田');
// endereço
$a['ja'] = array(
    'postal_code' => '104-0045',
    'country_name' => '日本',
    'province_name' => '東京都',
    'city_name' => '東京',
    'city_subregion' => '中央区',
    'county_name' => '明石町',
    'building' => 'マンション名123'
);

// tratamento pessoal
$t['pt'] = 'Sr(a)';
// nome da pessoa
$n['pt'] = array('name' => 'Fulano', 'surname' => 'Silva');
// endereço
$a['pt'] = array(
    'postal_code' => '06453-040',
    'country_name' => 'Brasil',
    'province_name' => 'SP',
    'city_name' => 'Barueri',
    'city_subregion' => '',
    'county_name' => 'Alphaville',
    'building' => 'Calçadas das Papoulas 123'
);

// regra de formatação para idioma japonês
$nf['ja'] = '%3$s %2$s %1$s'; // nome
$af['ja'] = '〒%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s'; // endereço

// regra de formatação para idioma português
$nf['pt'] = '%1$s %2$s %3$s'; // nome
$af['pt'] = '%7$s %6$s'.(empty($a[$l]['city_subregion'])? '': '- %5$s').', %4$s - %3$s, %1$s, %2$s'; // endereço

// escreve o nome
echo sprintf($nf[$l], $t[$l], $n[$l]['name'], $n[$l]['surname']).'<br>';
// escreve o endereço
echo sprintf(
    $af[$l],
    $a[$l]['postal_code'],
    $a[$l]['country_name'],
    $a[$l]['province_name'],
    $a[$l]['city_name'],
    $a[$l]['city_subregion'],
    $a[$l]['county_name'],
    $a[$l]['building']
);
```

Note que no momento de escrever, nada se altera. A estrutura dos dados nos arrays também não se altera. Ambos são iguais. O que faz a diferença é a regra de formatação, a qual informa a função `sprintf()` como e onde concatenar os outros parâmetros.

Experimente tentar chegar ao mesmo resultado sem usar a função. Torna-se algo complicado com muitas condicionais num emaranhado de códigos. Um pesadelo.

Isso aqui é um exemplo somente para 2 idiomas e é um caso muito simples e "fácil". Há coisas mais complexas, no entanto, o exemplo acima é o suficiente para o que pede a pergunta.

## Formatação de números

Há diversas outras utilidades de uso da função, como exemplo, converter um número em formato de notação científica para decimal/float.

```
$n = '5.3882598876953E-5';

// Esse trecho é para obter o exponente. Não é relevante para a questão
if ($p = strpos($n, '-')) {
    $decimals = strlen(substr($n, 0, $p - 1));
    $exponent = substr($n, $p + 1);
    $decimals += !empty($exponent)?$exponent - 1: 0;
} else {
    $decimals = strlen(substr($n, strpos($n, '.') + 1));
}

echo $n.'<br>'.sprintf('%.'.$decimals.'f', 1 * $n);
```

Imagine fazer isso sem a função `sprintf()`.

## Opinião

Por fim, opinião pessoal, mas sem querer desmerecer ninguém, acho desnecessário usar em tudo apenas para tornar o código bonito. Não faz sentido usar em casos onde o formato é estático, por exemplo. Estaria apenas consumindo processos desnecessários.

Exemplo de situação onde se faz desnecessário

```
$ch = curl_init(sprintf("%s/pages/%s/metrics/%s/data.json", $BASE_URI, $PAGE_ID, $METRIC_ID));
```

Não faz diferença se fizer uma concatenação organizada e padronizada.

```
$ch = curl_init($BASE_URI.'/pages/'.$PAGE_ID.'/metrics/'.$METRIC_ID'./data.json');
```

Conforme mencionado acima, o formato nesse caso é estático. Não há necessidade em usar um recurso de formatação dinâmica para algo estático.

```
$var1 = 'A';
$var2 = 'B';
$var3 = 'C';
echo $var1.''.$var2.''.$var3;
//Tempo: 596μs e algumas vezes a 610μs
// Não faz menor diferença usar vírgula ou ponto para concatenar.

$var1 = 'A';
$var2 = 'B';
$var3 = 'C';
echo sprintf('%1$s %2$s %3$s', $var1, $var2, $var3);
//Tempo: 786μs, porém, fica "flutuando" entre 880μs e 900μs
```

<sub>μs: microsegundos</sub>

A diferença para uma única e simples linha é de 2 a 3 microsegundos. Claro que para uma única execução é irrelevante, porém, se o aplicativo adota a função para fazer todas as concatenações, somatize-as. Se tiver 100 concatenações nos códigos, já deixa de ser irrelevante. Uma perda de performance por um "capricho" desnecessário.

<sub>Os exemplos tem finalidade didática. São meramente ilustrativos.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

O `sprintf` no PHP tem a basicamente a mesma função que no C, que é o de permitir que os recursos de formatação de valores disponíveis no `printf` possam ser aplicados a uma `string`, em vez de jogar no terminal.

Concordo, o exemplo que você deu não ilustra um caso onde o `sprintf` é realmente útil. Porem, na minha opinião, o código ficou mais limpo.

Mas eis uns caso onde ele pode auxiliar.

```
$pi = 3.14159265359;
$piResumido = sprintf("PI com duas casas decimais: %.2f",$pi);
echo $piResumido;
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenha em mente que a função `sprintf` pode fazer muito mais do que simplesmente reservar um espaço para ser preenchido com um argumento.

Ela é muito mais abrangente que isso. Através dessa função, você poderá formatar números com preenchimentos com zero a esquerda, poderá processar `integers` e `floats`.

Exemplo:

```
sprintf('%010.2f', 11.66); // '0000011.66'
sprintf('%010d', 11.66); // '0000000011'
```

Ou seja, o argumento pode ser processado de diversas maneiras.

Vale lembrar que, entre a chamada de uma função e uma declaração de uma string, o segundo caso seria mais performático.

Não estou aqui pra pregar microotimização (até mesmo porque eu odeio), mas creio que no exemplo descrito na pergunta não há benefício real em usar `sprintf`, embora tenho que confessar quem em alguns casos (como na elaboração de um caminho de arquivo, que é um processo que deve ser cuidadoso) eu uso `sprintf` pra fins de organização, pouco importando pra mim a performance, já que a performance não depende de uma função apenas, mas do conjunto da obra todo.

Não digo que priorize a legibilidade nem a performance, mas que seja moderado entre os dois, pois tudo nessa vida sem equilíbrio gera problemas.

Answer (score 2):

## Visibilidade

O sprintf pode facilitar o entendimento e melhorar a visibilidade de um trecho de código, leve em consideração os exemplos abaixo com variáveis pequenas:

```
// exemplo 1
$ch = curl_init(sprintf("%s/pages/%s/metrics/%s/data.json", $BASE_URI, $PAGE_ID, $METRIC_ID));

// exemplo 2
$ch = curl_init("$BASE_URI/pages/$PAGE_ID/metrics/$METRIC_ID/data.json");

// exemplo 3
$ch = curl_init("{$BASE_URI}/pages/{$PAGE_ID}/metrics/{$METRIC_ID}/data.json");

// exemplo 4
$ch = curl_init($BASE_URI.'/pages/'.$PAGE_ID.'/metrics/'.$METRIC_ID.'/data.json');
```

Todos ficaram fácil de entender, não houve muita diferença, embora eu prefira o exemplo 1 e 3.

Mas veja agora este outro cenário com váriaveis "grandes", fica ainda mais claro que o uso do sprintf melhora visibilidade.
Compare o exemplo feio com o bonito e perceba que é muito mais fácil entender no bonito o conjunto da informação que a string quer passar.

```
// feio
// Quebrei em linhas para ficar "menos pior"
$description  = "Ação: {$acao->getDescricao()} (ID: {$acao->getDescricao()}), ";
$description .= "Pessoa: {$pessoa->getDescricao()} (ID: {$pessoa->getId()}), ";
$description .= "Local: {$loja->getDescricao()} (ID: {$loja->getId()}), ";
$description .= "Data: {$data->format('d/m/Y')}";

// bonito
$description .= sprintf('Ação: %s (ID: %d), Pessoa: %s (ID: %d), Local: %s (ID: %d), Data: %s',
    $acao->getDescricao(),
    $acao->getId(),
    $pessoa->getDescricao(),
    $pessoa->getId(),
    $loja->getDescricao(),
    $loja->getId(),
    $data->format('d/m/Y')
);
```